# FacebookConnectionFactory connection GET request for "https://graph.facebook.com/me" resulted in 400 (Bad Request) MissingAuthorizationException:

Tags: spring-mvc, facebook, spring-social

I am trying to develop an app for Facebook. I wrote a facebook controller and created connectionFactory object, got the oAuth oprations and accessgrant object. I got the access token also But Once I try to create a connection

```
Connection<Facebook> connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(accessGrant);
```

I am getting the error :

> MissingAuthorizationException: Authorization is required for the operation, but the API binding was created without authorization.

Full stack trace :

```
[1/25/12 9:18:17:097 IST] 0000001a SystemOut     O oauthOperations :org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookOAuth2Template@46714671
[1/25/12 9:18:17:097 IST] 0000001a SystemOut     O authorizeUrl :https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxxxx&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A80%2FSpringSocial%2Fstart&scope=read_stream%2Cemail%2Cpublish_stream%2Coffline_access
[1/25/12 9:19:15:930 IST] 0000001a SystemOut     O oauthOperations authorizationCode :org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookOAuth2Template@46714671
[1/25/12 9:19:25:197 IST] 0000001a SystemOut     O accssTokentemp :xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[1/25/12 9:19:35:541 IST] 0000001a SystemOut     O facebook :org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookTemplate@21c221c2
[1/25/12 9:19:35:994 IST] 0000001a RestTemplate  W org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate handleResponseError GET request for "https://graph.facebook.com/me" resulted in 400 (Bad Request); invoking error handler
[1/25/12 9:19:36:041 IST] 0000001a servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet SpringSocial in application SpringSocialFacebookEar. Exception created : org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.social.MissingAuthorizationException: Authorization is required for the operation, but the API binding was created without authorization.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:574)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.serviceProxied(ServletWrapper.java:307)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleFragment(CacheHook.java:579)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleServlet(CacheHook.java:250)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:259)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1663)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)

Caused by: org.springframework.social.MissingAuthorizationException: Authorization is required for the operation, but the API binding was created without authorization.
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookErrorHandler.handleFacebookError(FacebookErrorHandler.java:95)
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookErrorHandler.handleError(FacebookErrorHandler.java:60)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:486)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:415)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:213)
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookTemplate.fetchObject(FacebookTemplate.java:165)
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.UserTemplate.getUserProfile(UserTemplate.java:50)
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.UserTemplate.getUserProfile(UserTemplate.java:46)
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookAdapter.setConnectionValues(FacebookAdapter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookAdapter.setConnectionValues(FacebookAdapter.java:30)
    at org.springframework.social.connect.support.AbstractConnection.setValues(AbstractConnection.java:172)
    at org.springframework.social.connect.support.AbstractConnection.initKey(AbstractConnection.java:135)
    at org.springframework.social.connect.support.OAuth2Connection.(OAuth2Connection.java:73)
    at org.springframework.social.connect.support.OAuth2ConnectionFactory.createConnection(OAuth2ConnectionFactory.java:58)
    at com.tgt.social.controller.FaceBookConnectController.facebookConnect(FaceBookConnectController.java:107)
```

My Controller class :

```
@Controller
public class FaceBookConnectController {

    private static OAuth2Operations oauthOperations = null;
    private static FacebookConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;
    private static OAuth2Parameters params = null;

    @RequestMapping("/start")
    public ModelAndView facebookConnect(Model model,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
        Security.setProperty("ssl.SocketFactory.provider", "com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl");   
        Security.setProperty("ssl.ServerSocketFactory.provider", "com.ibm.jsse2.SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl");
        System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "localhost");
        System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8888");

        String clientId = "xxxxxxxxx";
        String clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        String redirectUrl = "http://localhost:80/SpringSocial/start";

        try {
            String authorizationCode = request.getParameter("code");
            if(null != authorizationCode){
                MultiValueMap paramsMap1 = new LinkedMultiValueMap();
                System.out.println("oauthOperations authorizationCode :"+oauthOperations);
                //paramsMap.set("client_id", clientId);
                //paramsMap.set("client_secret", clientSecret);
                //paramsMap.set("code", authorizationCode);
                paramsMap1.set("redirect_uri", redirectUrl);
                paramsMap1.set("grant_type", "authorization_code");
                paramsMap1.set("scope","read_stream,user_about_me,user_birthday,user_likes,user_status,email,publish_stream,offline_access");
                //AccessGrant accessGrant = oauthOperations.exchangeForAccess(authorizationCode, redirectUrl, paramsMap1);
                System.out.println("connectionFactory authorizationCode :"+connectionFactory);
                AccessGrant accessGrant = connectionFactory.getOAuthOperations().exchangeForAccess(authorizationCode, redirectUrl, paramsMap1);
                String accssTokentemp = accessGrant.getAccessToken();
                System.out.println("accssTokentemp :"+accssTokentemp);
                String scope_p = accessGrant.getScope();
                System.out.println("scope_p :"+scope_p);
                Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(accssTokentemp);
                System.out.println("facebook :"+facebook);
                Connection<Facebook> connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(accessGrant);
                //FacebookProfile userProfile = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile();
                System.out.println("connection :"+connection);

            }else{
                MultiValueMap paramsMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap();
                connectionFactory = new FacebookConnectionFactory(clientId,clientSecret);
                System.out.println("connectionFactory :"+connectionFactory);
                oauthOperations = connectionFactory.getOAuthOperations();
                params = new OAuth2Parameters();
                params.setRedirectUri(redirectUrl);
                params.setScope("read_stream,user_about_me,user_birthday,user_likes,user_status,email,publish_stream,offline_access");
                paramsMap.set("client_id", clientId);
                paramsMap.set("client_secret", clientSecret);
                paramsMap.set("code", authorizationCode);
                paramsMap.set("redirect_uri", redirectUrl);
                paramsMap.set("grant_type", "authorization_code");
                System.out.println("oauthOperations :"+oauthOperations);
                String authorizeUrl = oauthOperations.buildAuthorizeUrl(GrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE, params);
                System.out.println("authorizeUrl :"+authorizeUrl);
                response.sendRedirect(authorizeUrl);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       return null;  
    }
}
```

Please let me know what is wrong here?
Is the instantiation is not correct for connectionFactory object.

Comment: The facebook object which I am getting is showing as authorized.I tried with the API : facebook.isAuthorized().and this returns true

Answer (score 1):

You need to addConnection to the usersConnectionRepository since social tries to locate a user's already established connection if any, and tries to get it authorized and use it